# Get value of input text control on click on href in Jquery

Tags: jquery, text, input, get

I have a function CheckMobile(MobNumber) and it will check all duplicate record of MobNumber which is passed in function. I want to use jquery to implement this.

```
<td><input type='text' name='Phone2' class='required' maxlength='10' /></td>  
<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="CheckMobile(Phone2)">Check Phone</a></td>
```

and my jquery function is:

```
function CheckMobile(MobNumber) {
    debugger;
   var phone = $(MobNumber).val();
   alert(phone);

}
```

But it does not work. In function i am getting undefined value.Please help how to get value of phone.

Comment: What is `Phone2` in the onclick? Is it a variable or did you mean it to be a selector for the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get at the input by doing:

```
$("input[name='Phone2']")
```

In jQuery and then use `.val()` to get the value. (Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhT94/)

EDIT:

Didn't notice you'd given it an ID, in that case you could just do:

```
$("#Phone2").val()
```

So in your original code change:

```
$(MobNumber).val()
```

To

```
$("#" + MobNumber).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your selector there, it's not valid :

```
      var phone = $(MobNumber).val();
```

You should access by the attribute name instead like this

```
  var phone = $("input[name='Phone2']").val();
```

Comment: This is wrong, the issue is that `$(MobNumber)` goes to `$('Phone2)` which is not a valid selector.

Comment: I don't see in what my code is wrong at all if you replace his lin by my is working. And my answer is that the selector is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you use the selector.

```
<td><input type='text' name='Phone2' id='Phone2' class='required' maxlength='10' /></td>  
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="CheckMobile('Phone2')">Check Phone</a></td>
```

Not that we append '#' and concatenate with the passed string parameter

```
 function CheckMobile(MobNumber) {
        debugger;
       var phone = $('#'+MobNumber).val();
       alert(phone);

    }
```